# Comparing two Google Sheets and finding unique values (only on one of the sheets)

Tags: javascript, filter, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have two sheets and both have a list of emails. Sheet A is smaller (around 800 entries) and Sheet B is like 10,000 entries. I need to find emails on Sheet A that aren't on Sheet B, but not vice versa (because obviously most of the entries in Sheet B aren't in Sheet A).

I was looking at the =UNIQUE formula but it looks like that only returns unique entries in one column. That could work if I shoved both columns of emails into an array and sorted that, but then I'd get the problem of having EVERY unique email as a result, which isn't what I need.

I think maybe VLOOKUP could do this, but I have absolutely no idea how VLOOKUP works. Essentially I need like the opposite of filterByText, but I'm not sure how that would work. Perhaps Sheets has a universal ! modifier, but if it does I don't know what it is.

Comment: You can try using `MATCH` to determine if a value is within a range.

Comment: With the size of the comparisons I'm making it seems like the better thing to do would be to put both email columns into arrays and then search arrays for Unique values. Doesn't `MATCH` only return the location of a match in the array? I guess I could make that work, but that's still the opposite of what I want. Unless I filter out everything that DOESN'T match, I suppose....

Answer (score 1):

You could filter out the matching email addresses..
See if this works (on sheet A):

```
=filter(A1:A, isna(match(A1:A, 'SheetB'!A1:A,0)))
```

Change ranges to suit.